# Whenever I build an APK with multidex, the build always fails with a DexArchiveMergerException: unable to merge dex

Tags: android

I've just upgraded my Android Studio to verion 3.0, and now whenever I build an APK that uses the multidex dependency, it always fails with that error. Even with multidex 1.0.1 it doesn't work.

Any solution except Clean Project and Invalidate Caches / Restart (neither worked)?

Comment: Do u extend the application class. Also check the docs, depending on minimum sdk version u need to do it diffrently

Comment: also add ur gradle code and Application file code in here for us to see

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: did your try `./gradlew clean` then `./gradlew assemble` ?